Trace function calls of child process using /proc/pid/maps and ptrace
I am trying to code a tracer for any C program that displays all the functions that are being called. Here is an example:
$./tracer toto.out
+ Entering main at 0x123456789
'I am in Toto's main'
+ Entering toto at 0x123456AAA
'I am in toto'
+ Entering tutu at 0x123456BBB
'I am in tutu'

With toto.out being the simple program:
void tutu(void) {
    char msg[] = "I am in tutu\n";
    size_t len = strlen(msg);
    write(1, msg, len);
}
void toto(void) {
    char msg[] = "I am in toto\n";
    size_t len = strlen(msg);
    write(1, msg, len);
}
int main(void) {
    char msg[] = "I am in toto's main\n";
    size_t len = strlen(msg);
    write(1, msg, len);
    toto();
    tutu();
    return 0;
}

Here is everything I have for now:
I already parsed the /proc/[child_pid]/maps file and listed the symbol list from the ELF64 header of every executable file:
59bcd6a5f000-59bcd6a60000 r-xp 00001000 103:04 5244516                   /home/julian/epitech/ftrace/toto.out
76ac3ba28000-76ac3bbbd000 r-xp 00028000 103:04 5899229                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
76ac3be00000-76ac3be06000 r-xp 00000000 103:04 5948263                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
76ac3c049000-76ac3c04a000 r-xp 00001000 103:04 5907768                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
76ac3c06f000-76ac3c099000 r-xp 00002000 103:04 5898261                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Which gives me the following list of symbols (excluding symbols that are on non executable segments) thanks to a simple math to retrieve the global / mapped address of the symbol.

Executable segment address - segment offset + symbol local address (Elf64_Sym->st_value)


ie for toto.out main: 0x59bcd6a5f000 - 0x1000 + 0x128d = 0x59bcd6a628d

/home/me/epitech/ftrace/toto.out at address 0x000059bcd6a5f000->0x000059bcd6a60000 (offset 0x1000) :
    _init
        0x000059bcd6a5f000->    0x000059bcd6a5f000 (local addr 0x1000) (size 0x0).
    main
        0x000059bcd6a5f28d->    0x000059bcd6a5f32d (local addr 0x128d) (size 0xa0).
    _start
        0x000059bcd6a5f0c0->    0x000059bcd6a5f0e6 (local addr 0x10c0) (size 0x26).
    _IO_stdin_used
        0x000059bcd6a60000->    0x000059bcd6a60004 (local addr 0x2000) (size 0x4).
    tutu
        0x000059bcd6a5f1a9->    0x000059bcd6a5f21b (local addr 0x11a9) (size 0x72).
    toto
        0x000059bcd6a5f21b->    0x000059bcd6a5f28d (local addr 0x121b) (size 0x72).
    _fini
        0x000059bcd6a5f330->    0x000059bcd6a5f330 (local addr 0x1330) (size 0x0).
    frame_dummy
        0x000059bcd6a5f1a0->    0x000059bcd6a5f1a0 (local addr 0x11a0) (size 0x0).
    __do_global_dtors_aux
        0x000059bcd6a5f160->    0x000059bcd6a5f160 (local addr 0x1160) (size 0x0).
    register_tm_clones
        0x000059bcd6a5f120->    0x000059bcd6a5f120 (local addr 0x1120) (size 0x0).
    deregister_tm_clones
        0x000059bcd6a5f0f0->    0x000059bcd6a5f0f0 (local addr 0x10f0) (size 0x0).
-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at address 0x000076ac3ba28000->0x000076ac3bbbd000 (offset 0x28000) :
    I cannot find the .strtab to name the symbol...
-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 at address 0x000076ac3be00000->0x000076ac3be06000 (offset 0x0) :
    Same .strtab issue...
-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 at address 0x000076ac3c04e000->0x000076ac3c04f000 (offset 0x1000) :
    Same...
-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at address 0x000076ac3c06f000->0x000076ac3c099000 (offset 0x2000) :
    Same...
-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 at address 0x000076ac3c049000->0x000076ac3c04a000 (offset 0x1000) :
    __libpthread_version_placeholder@GLIBC_2.3.2
        0x000076ac3c049100->    0x000076ac3c049105 (local 0x1100) (size 0x5).
    ..a lot of other irrelevant symbols for toto...

Whenever I detect the call near opcode using PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, I wait until the jump has been made to compare the RIP register to my list of symbol's addresses:
// old rip before call
Re-Extended Instruction Pointer 0x000059bcd6a5f2f9. (+0x5)

// Debug printing the opcode and the operand when I find a near call (opcode 0xe8) to main
Opcode 0xe8b2 0xfd, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe8, 0x18, 0xff...

// Debug printing the new RIP
Re-Extended Instruction Pointer 0x000059bcd6a5f0b0. (-0x249)

// Current rip in indeed inside toto.out's executable segment but doesn't match toto function address 0x000059bcd6a5f28d
+ Entering unknow at 0x59bcd6a5f080

// Child process prints
'I am in toto'

// Same for tutu, somehow jumps to the same address as toto
Re-Extended Instruction Pointer 0x000059bcd6a5f1ff. (+0x5)
Opcode 0xe87c 0xfe, 0xff, 0xff, 0x90, 0x48, 0x8b...
Re-Extended Instruction Pointer 0x000059bcd6a5f080. (-0x17f)
+ Entering unknow at 0x59bcd6a5f080
'I am in tutu'
...

Here is the objdump of toto.out for reference:
...a lot of symbols omitted for shortening this post...
00000000000011a9 <tutu>:
    11a9:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    11ad:   55                      push   %rbp
    11ae:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    11b1:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
    11b5:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    11bc:   00 00 
    11be:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    11c2:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    11c4:   48 b8 49 20 61 6d 20    movabs $0x206e69206d612049,%rax
    11cb:   69 6e 20 
    11ce:   48 89 45 ea             mov    %rax,-0x16(%rbp)
    11d2:   c7 45 f2 74 75 74 75    movl   $0x75747574,-0xe(%rbp)
    11d9:   66 c7 45 f6 0a 00       movw   $0xa,-0xa(%rbp)
    11df:   48 8d 45 ea             lea    -0x16(%rbp),%rax
    11e3:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    11e6:   e8 a5 fe ff ff          call   1090 <strlen@plt>
    11eb:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
    11ef:   48 8b 55 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
    11f3:   48 8d 45 ea             lea    -0x16(%rbp),%rax
    11f7:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
    11fa:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
    11ff:   e8 7c fe ff ff          call   1080 <write@plt>
    1204:   90                      nop
    1205:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
    1209:   64 48 2b 04 25 28 00    sub    %fs:0x28,%rax
    1210:   00 00 
    1212:   74 05                   je     1219 <tutu+0x70>
    1214:   e8 87 fe ff ff          call   10a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
    1219:   c9                      leave  
    121a:   c3                      ret
000000000000121b <toto>:
    121b:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    121f:   55                      push   %rbp
    1220:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1223:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
    1227:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    122e:   00 00 
    1230:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    1234:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    1236:   48 b8 49 20 61 6d 20    movabs $0x206e69206d612049,%rax
    123d:   69 6e 20 
    1240:   48 89 45 ea             mov    %rax,-0x16(%rbp)
    1244:   c7 45 f2 74 6f 74 6f    movl   $0x6f746f74,-0xe(%rbp)
    124b:   66 c7 45 f6 0a 00       movw   $0xa,-0xa(%rbp)
    1251:   48 8d 45 ea             lea    -0x16(%rbp),%rax
    1255:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    1258:   e8 33 fe ff ff          call   1090 <strlen@plt>
    125d:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
    1261:   48 8b 55 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
    1265:   48 8d 45 ea             lea    -0x16(%rbp),%rax
    1269:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
    126c:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
    1271:   e8 0a fe ff ff          call   1080 <write@plt>
    1276:   90                      nop
    1277:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
    127b:   64 48 2b 04 25 28 00    sub    %fs:0x28,%rax
    1282:   00 00 
    1284:   74 05                   je     128b <toto+0x70>
    1286:   e8 15 fe ff ff          call   10a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
    128b:   c9                      leave
    128c:   c3                      ret
000000000000128d <main>:
    128d:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1291:   55                      push   %rbp
    1292:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1295:   48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
    1299:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    12a0:   00 00 
    12a2:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    12a6:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    12a8:   48 b8 49 20 61 6d 20    movabs $0x206e69206d612049,%rax
    12af:   69 6e 20 
    12b2:   48 ba 74 6f 74 6f 27    movabs $0x6d2073276f746f74,%rdx
    12b9:   73 20 6d 
    12bc:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
    12c0:   48 89 55 e8             mov    %rdx,-0x18(%rbp)
    12c4:   c7 45 f0 61 69 6e 0a    movl   $0xa6e6961,-0x10(%rbp)
    12cb:   c6 45 f4 00             movb   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
    12cf:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
    12d3:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    12d6:   e8 b5 fd ff ff          call   1090 <strlen@plt>
    12db:   48 89 45 d8             mov    %rax,-0x28(%rbp)
    12df:   48 8b 55 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdx
    12e3:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
    12e7:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
    12ea:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
    12ef:   e8 8c fd ff ff          call   1080 <write@plt>
    12f4:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
    12f9:   e8 b2 fd ff ff          call   10b0 <sleep@plt>
    12fe:   e8 18 ff ff ff          call   121b <toto>
    1303:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
    1308:   e8 a3 fd ff ff          call   10b0 <sleep@plt>
    130d:   e8 97 fe ff ff          call   11a9 <tutu>
    1312:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1317:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
    131b:   64 48 2b 14 25 28 00    sub    %fs:0x28,%rdx
    1322:   00 00 
    1324:   74 05                   je     132b <main+0x9e>
    1326:   e8 75 fd ff ff          call   10a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
    132b:   c9                      leave  
    132c:   c3                      ret 

Finally, here are all the question I need help with:

Am I getting the correct global address ?
If the addresses are correct, why is the message printed although I am not on the main function ?
Why is the RIP being jumped to the same address BEFORE main, toto and tutu for both function ?

Thanks to anyone who took the time to read this massive post and thanks + 1 for those knowledgeable enough to answer it
